# How can I use R to find things that repeat between sets?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genomics

Say I have three datasets, each is a list of differentially expressed genes. How can I use R to find the genes that repeat in all three sets?

An example of the dataset would be:
(there would be hundreds of genes in each set)
Dataset 1:
KRAS
MAPK1
CYCS
ABCD
ABCG1
TMEM51

Dataset 2:
CYCS
GAGE12J
TMEM51
ABCG1
MAPK1

Dataset 3:
KRAS
ABCG1
TMEM51
ALB
RGS13
CYCS

The output I would get for this sample would be ABCG1, CYCS, and TMEM51, because those are the only ones that show up in all three steps.

I tried using the dplyr package,
`

```
# Function to extract gene symbols from CSV file
extract_genes <- function(file_path) {
df <- read.csv(file_path, header = TRUE)  # Read CSV file
genes <- df$GeneSymbol  # Extract gene symbols column
return(genes)
}

# File paths for your datasets
file_paths <- c(" Significance 1.csv", 
            "Significance 2.csv", 
            "Significance 3.csv", 
            "Significance 4.csv")

# List to store gene symbols from each dataset
gene_lists <- list()

# Extract gene symbols from each dataset
for (file_path in file_paths) {
gene_lists[[file_path]] <- extract_genes(file_path)
}

# Find common genes across all datasets
common_genes <- Reduce(intersect, gene_lists)

# Print common genes
print(common_genes)`
```

I got this response: NULL

However, I know that there are genes that are present in all datasets so this result must be wrong.

Comment: Your code works for me when I recreate an example folder structure and run your code/functions - perhaps it's because you have a space in the first `file_paths`? (ie, " Significance 1.csv" should be "Significance 1.csv". What happens when you run `extract_genes(file_paths[1])`?